# Установить state для определенного пользователя

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу бота на python и aiogram. Суть в том, что администратор принимает (или отклоняет) заявки пользователей. Соответственно, когда администратор нажимает на кнопку в своем чате, нужно поменять состояние пользователя (uid его известен). Нигде не нашел, как это сделать.

То есть я ищу что-то вроде

```
dp.set_state(uid, User.acepted)
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В aiogram установить состояние любого пользователя в любом чате можно с помощью следующей конструкции:

```
state = dp.current_state(chat=chat_id, user=user_id)
await state.set_state(User.accepted)
```

Где: 
**dp** - объект класса Dispatcher
**chat_id** - id чата, который должен быть равен id пользователя, если это переписка с пользователем
**User.accepted** - состояние в которое мы хотим привести пользователя

Comment: Спасибо большое!