# Aiogram 2 Python. Как изменить state другого пользователя

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Допустим, пользователь нажал команду /next и прекратил чат с другим пользователем в боте.
Тогда нужно изменить state и у того человека,с которым он только что общался. Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267197/aiogram-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-state-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как установить state для определенного пользователя Aiogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267197/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-state-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-aiogram)